# SQL Server table check logic failing for certain rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with 5 columns

```
KeyInstn, KeyFndg, KeyIndex, KeyGeographyTree, KeyDevelopmentEntityRole
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to only allow following rows by applying a SQL Server table check:

1. When only `KeyGeographyTree` is populated, then `KeyInstn, KeyFndg, KeyIndex` must be null and `KeyDevelopmentEnityRole` must be equal to 12.
2. When `KeyInstn` is populated, `KeyGeographyTree` can be populated but the other two columns `KeyIndex, KeyFndg` must be NULL.
3. Other two combinations ie., when `KeyIndex` and `KeyGeographyTree` are populated, then `KeyInstn and KeyFndg` must be null, or when `KeyFndg` and `KeyGeographyTree` are populated, then `KeyInstn` and `KeyIndex` must be null.

In other words any of the columns `KeyInstn, KeyFndg, KeyIndex` can be populated at the same time but `KeyGeographyTree` can be populated alone or in combination with any one of the other 3 columns.

This is the table check which I've written and I'm tweaking around it:

```
ISNUMERIC(KeyInstn) + ISNUMERIC(KeyFndg) + ISNUMERIC(KeyIndex) = 1 
OR (KeyGeographyTree IS NOT NULL AND KeyDevelopmentEntityRole = 12))
```

The following conditions shouldn't pass which are passing at the moment

1. KeyInstn = 123, KeyGeographyTree = 999 and KeyDevelopmentEntityRole = 12
2. KeyInstn = 123, KeyGeographyTree = NULL and KeyDevelopmentEntityRole = 12

Answer (score 0):

The following table check worked satisfying all the cases:

`(ISNUMERIC(KeyInstn) + ISNUMERIC(KeyFndg) + ISNUMERIC(KeyIndex) = 1 
 AND KeyDevelopmentEntityRole <> 12) OR (ISNUMERIC(KeyInstn) + ISNUMERIC(KeyFndg) 
 + ISNUMERIC(KeyIndex) = 0 AND ISNUMERIC(KeyGeographyTree) = 1 
 AND KeyDevelopmentEntityRole = 12)`